# Javascript code optimizing: Multiple use of allocative function with variable hooks

Tags: javascript, optimization

I do have an initializing allocative function with hooks to optional call other functions. The Idea is, that the (other) functions could be written individual to the project to add individual needed features.

The mechanic works fine if there is only one call on a page.

Now I would like to realize multiple use of that function on one page. That means on every call the allocative function should call hooks with different and individual code for every single call. That means: after I called function and hooks the first time I have to change the code of the hooks for the second call.

Up to now I 'reset' the hook functions before starting the second call and coding the hooks new.

The question is about: is there a way to write better, a more easier and maybe more elegant code?

I would prefer a mechanic without the 'reset' but starting directly with coding the hooks for the second call. Is that possible maybe with using another scope for the variables? The solution should be realized without use of classes and in vanilla Javascript (no jQuery).

Here is the simplified(!) code to demonstrate the mechanic:

```
<h1 id="hd1" class="heading main normal">Testing JS</h1>

<h2 id="hd2" class="subheading article">Another headline</h2>




<script type="text/javascript">


    let hookBeforeStart,hookAfterDone;   // initializing vars for hooks

    function resetHookFuncions(){
        hookBeforeStart = {};
        hookAfterDone = {};
    }   

    function allocativeFunction( selector ){

        const $element = document.getElementById( selector );
        const classes = $element.classList;
        const eHtml = $element.innerHTML;

        // hooks
        if(typeof(hookBeforeStart) == 'function'){
            hookBeforeStart({ $element, classes });
        }
        if(typeof(hookAfterDone) == 'function'){
            hookAfterDone({ $element, eHtml });
        }

    }


    window.onload = function(){


        // ### first call allocative function with individual hooks

        console.log('first call');

        hookBeforeStart = function( p ){
            console.log( p.classes );
        };
        
        hookAfterDone = function( p ){
            console.log( p.eHtml );
        }
        
        allocativeFunction('hd2');
        

        
        // ### second call allocative function with same hooks but other individual code

        console.log('second call');
        
        //###### RESET
        //###### SEEMS TO BE LESS ELEGANT AND COMPLICATED 
        //###### IS THERE A BETTER WAY WITHOUT RESET????
        resetHookFuncions(); 

        // note: hookBeforeStart not needed for second call
        // --> has been (needed to be) deleted by reset

        hookAfterDone = function( p ){
            console.log( p.$element );
        }
    
        allocativeFunction('hd1');

    
    } // window.onload

</script>
```

All hints and suggestions to do it better are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you pass the hooks as arguments to the function? No good reason to make them global variables.

Comment: @Bergi: Indeed no good reason anyway and ugly code on top ... Well. Sometimes there are so many trees in the head so you are not able to see the forest ;-) Thx for your answer. That’s the solution I was looking for … and was not able to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

To all who may look for a similar problem in the future: here is the solution. Thx to @Bergi for the hint showing the way.

```
<h1 id="hd1" class="heading main normal">Testing JS</h1>

<h2 id="hd2" class="subheading article">Another headline</h2>



<script type="text/javascript">


    function allocativeFunction( selector, hookBeforeStart, hookAfterDone ){

        const $element = document.getElementById( selector );
        const classes = $element.classList;
        const eHtml = $element.innerHTML;

        // hooks: names set by parameter
        if(typeof(hookBeforeStart) == 'function'){
            hookBeforeStart({ $element, classes });
        }
        if(typeof(hookAfterDone) == 'function'){
            hookAfterDone({ $element, eHtml });
        }

    }


    window.onload = function(){

            
        // ### first call function and individual hooks

        console.log('first call');

        function hookBeforeStart1( p ){
            console.log( p.classes );
        };
        
        function hookAfterDone1( p ){
            console.log( p.eHtml );
        }
        
        allocativeFunction('hd2', hookBeforeStart1, hookAfterDone1 );           
             

        // ### second call function: hooks with other name and other code
        // calling in separate scope possible
        (function () {
                
            console.log('second call');

            // note: hookBeforeStart not needed for second call

            function hookOtherNameAfterDone( p ){
                console.log( p.$element );
            }
        
            allocativeFunction('hd1', null, hookOtherNameAfterDone );
            
        })();

    
    } // window.onload

</script>
```